# How to increase font size of just chapter names in latex

Tags: latex

need of a small guidance here.
I am using report class, and I do not need chapter numbers for every chapter, just the chapter names.

Is there a way to increase just the font size of the chapter names?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Observation:
[image: Attached code output]

[image: Wanted result with greater font size]

Chapter number is to be removed. I would really appreciate any guidance to increase the font size of the chapter name.

I tried the following to remove chapter numbers. But font size is causing a little concern

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{5pt}{\huge}
```

Thanks

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: did you test your new code? This won't compile

Comment: Please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the font size of the chapter title with the third argument of `\titleformat`. In your example, this was `\normalsize`, change this to whatever size you like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{56pt}{64pt}\bfseries}{}{5pt}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which part in this is responsible for setting the font size of the chapter title? Is it `{\fontsize{56pt}{64pt}`? Because if so, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Not every font has the size 56pt. Which font do you use?

Comment: I use the default font.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Try with `\usepackage{lmodern}` as shown in my answer

Comment: The font size (56pt) is now applied to both the chapter header (the one in which the chapter index is displayed)  and the chapter name.